# Problem writing delphi 64 bit application using microsoft access databases

Tags: delphi

What happens:
create delphi 32 bit application to open up a ms access database, the newer accdb one, created with access 2013 32 bit version.   Using TADOConnection and dbgo.  Works great.
Change to 64 bit platform, as soon as I try opening up a table at runtime, I get the "provider cannot be found error".  Although I can open up a table within the IDE.  OS is windows 10 pro 64 bit.

I have tried uninstalling ms office, and then downloading and installing the access 2013 database engine, the 64 bit version one.  If I drop a TADOConnection on a new project, there are no MS ACE 12 or 15 providers.  If I uninstall the 64 bit database engine, and install the 32 bit database engine, I see providers in both delphi 32 and 64 bit target platforms.  I tried installing the 64 bit database engine using the "passive" parameter but microsoft has apparently caught on to this trick and will give the usual error message about you cannot install both 32 and 64 bit versions.  So I tried using the 2010 versions of the database engines and still get error messages, although different ones.

It just feels like I'm missing something here.  The weird thing is that in the IDE, using 32 bit access engine and 64 bit delphi target platform, I can make the connection active and open a table.  But if I try and open a table at run time I get the error.  I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling delphi.

Comment: It works in the IDE because the IDE and all design-time components are 32-bit, regardless of whether the target platform is 32 or 64 bit. The 64 bit stuff only affects things once you're running your compiled application.

Comment: I suspected as much.  So there really isn't  any way to create a 64 bit application to work with access databases, using the IDE?   It's not the end of the world but just seemed like by now there should be a way to make it work.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: There is - you have to have the 64-bit Access DB engine installed when the app is launched, which means you won't be able to open the tables or queries in the IDE. You can probably do both by installing the DB engine (without an Access installation) manually. If you have a 64-bit version of Office installed, then just install the 32-bit version of the DB engine (not Access or Office 32 bit). While you can't have both versions of Office or Access installed at the same time, there's nothing stopping you from having both sets of DB drivers available.

Comment: I sat down and really played around with this to clarify things down.  Microsoft has cracked down on the /passive or /quiet parameters when installing the office 2013 database engines.  No matter what combination I chose, it would always prevent me from installing both 32 and 64 bit at the same time.  For example, I installed office 64 bit and tried installing the 32 bit database engine.   Always the error message, you cannot install XX bit program with YY bit program already installed.

Comment: Having said that, I was able to remove office from my workstation, and then install the 32 bit database engine. (I could have left 32 bit office on for this as well, but knew I would be uninstalling the 32 bit at some point and it's a lot faster for the engine :-)) I could then create both the 32 bit and 64 bit target applications.  You can build the connection string in the data link properties under the 32 bit target, and see the provider just fine, in my case I used the office 15 database engine.

Comment: The good news is that when you go to create your 64 bit target, even though you cannot see the provider in the data link build wizard, it is still there and uses the exact same name (64 bit vs 32 bit).  So using the 32 bit engine installed, I created both 32 bit and 64 bit targets.  With the 32 bit database engine installed, I can run my 32 bit target just fine, and debug completely in the IDE.  The 64 bit target as expected complains "provider not found".

Comment: Uninstall the 32 bit database engine, and installed the 64 bit database engine.  Try and run the 32 bit target and get, as expected, "provider not found".  Run the 64 bit target and everything works fine.  In the IDE, you can debug etc just fine, but you cannot use the ide to open tables etc like you mentioned.  So it does work, but you really want to have two workstations set up I think with different 32 bit vs 64 bit situations.  Otherwise you are looking at uninstalling and reinstalling office, and who wants the fun of that lol.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot mark your comment as an answer to my question, I am too new I guess, but thank you for your help it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: You can't mark a comment as an answer, because it's just a comment. What you should do is to turn what you've written in the last few comments into an answer below. You can even mark it as accepted. It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions here - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: In one of your comments you say that 64 bit database uses the same provider name as 32 bit one. Is this provider name predetermined by Microsoft or can you set your own during installation? It it is the latter try to set different provider names for 32 bit and 64 bit database engines. This way you might be able to install both at the same time. just my thought on this topic despite the fact that I have no actual experience with this.

Comment: SilverWarrior it's predermined so no way to pick your own.  Although there probably is a way by installing one and changing some registry settings.  I did try installing 32 bit Access 2013 engine, and then the 64 bit Access 2010 engine, which did install, but started getting some weird errors and crashes so abandoned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the short answer is yes it will work, but there are a few caveats:

- You can only install either the 32 bit or 64 bit access 2013 engine drivers or Office, or any combination of those two.  Microsoft has disabled the /passive or /quiet way to bypass that.  So you can't install both 32 bit and 64 bit at the same time.  (at least in a straightforward manner)  You can go to control panel and see which ODBC drivers are installed via admin tools.
- The IDE is 32 bit, and can only see 32 bit access engine providers when they are installed (via tadoconnect build data provider). Any 64 bit providers installed are not visible in the tadoconnect build connection string wizard.
- The good news is that the 32 bit and 64 bit access engine providers have exactly the same provider name.  So if you install the 32 bit drivers, create your 32 bit project, you can also create your 64 bit target as well.
- with 32 bit drivers installed, your 32 bit target application will debug and run normally.  If you try and run the 64 bit target, you'll get "provider not found"
- with 64 bit drivers installed, your 64 bit target application will run normally, and the 32 bit application will give the "provider not found" error.  In addition, in the IDE, you will not be able to see the data provider via the build connection string in tadoconnect, just leave it alone as it has the exact same name.  You can run or debug your 64 bit app, just assume the data provider is correct even though you can't see it.

A thanks to Ken White for a point in the right direction.